# can't get session singleton in EcomDev PHPUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, magento, testing, phpunit

After some serious debugging I have found I can't call to get a session object in Magento when running a test with EcomDev_PHPUnit module

any singleton/model call i.e. `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')` or `Mage::getModel('customer/session')` eventually throws an exception from `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Controller_Request_Http::getHttpHost()` saying `Cannot run controller test, because the host is not set for base url.`  which is caused because the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` index is not set

Is there something in the configuration that I could be missing to cause this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a problem related to Magento session initialization that is internal core part of Magento. In order to get rid of this error is to use a mock object, that does not use standard Magento session initialization process, since it uses core php session.

The replacement of session object with mock can be done by using the following code if you've extended your test case from one of the EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case classes.

```
$sessionMock = $this->getModelMockBuilder('admin/session')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor() // This one removes session_start and other methods usage
        ->setMethods(null) // Enables original methods usage, because by default it overrides all methods
        ->getMock();
$this->replaceByMock('singleton', 'admin/session', $sessionMock);
```

Comment: @Ivan - what's the problem you talked about, more exactly?

Comment: @Ivan any chance that you could make the EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case_Controller::reset() method public so that the base_url and other params can be initialized by non-controller tests? That would help with this issue...

Comment: Important note: Always use Ivan's way of mocking sessions. I found that using something like $this->replaceByMock('singleton', 'admin/session', $this->mockSession('admin/session')); causes the mock to stick around during different tests, potentially breaking stuff

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve a similar issue I had with `checkout/session`... tried using a similar way that @barbazul described with bad results.

Answer (score 0):

You can set host in phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit ....>
    ...
    <php>
        <server name='HTTP_HOST' value='http://local.mysite.com' />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```