# How to mock Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart') in php-unit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I have this foo() method and I need to add unit test case for this method testFoo() in Magento. but unable to mock Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart').

**source method**

```
public function foo()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getFunctionName();
}
```

**test function**

```
public function testFoo(): void
{
    //$this->className :: Project_Catalog_Helper_Test
    $expected = 'string';
    $this->className->method('getSingleton')->willReturn($this->cart);
    $this->cart->method('getQuote')->willReturn($this->cart);
    $this->cart->method('getFunctionName')->willReturn('string');
    $this->assertEquals(
        $this->className->foo(),
        $expected
    );
}
```

When I run, php-unit getting this error log.

```
MacBook-Pro % ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/src/app/code/local/project/Catalog/Helper/OrderTest.php
PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.11
Configuration: /project_path/phpunit.xml.dist

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 150 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Project_Catalog_Helper_Test::testFoo
Error: Call to a member function getCode() on bool

/project_path/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php:103
/project_path/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1394
/project_path/app/Mage.php:517
/project_path/app/Mage.php:531
/project_path/app/code/community/Checkout/Model/Cart.php:20
/project_path/app/code/local/project/Catalog/Helper/Order.php:21
/project_path/tests/src/app/code/local/project/Catalog/Helper/OrderTest.php:100
/project_path/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:53
```

Need some solution, how to mock Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart').

**Note**: I can not change main method, since its legacy code. only unit-test case needs to added.

Answer (score 2):

You can not mock `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')` as it is a static function in the global namespace.

However you can inject a mock using [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) injecting a checkout-card mock.  Afterwards restore the original singleton at that place.

Compare *[with existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612349/367456)* that inherits this from the EComDev Testsuite that should have more pointers how to handle the innards with *[PHP Reflection](https://www.php.net/reflection)*.